# Is HTTP idempotence guaranteed even if another request comes in between retries?

Tags: http

Let's say there is an API for a `user` resource with the required fields `id`, `username` and an optional field `email`. Example valid resources in JSON are `{"id": 1, "username": "jsmith", "email": "jsmith@example.com"}` and `{"id": 2, "username": "jdoe"}`.

Let's say there is a PUT method to create/replace a user, DELETE to delete it, PATCH to change some attributes, and of course GET to retrieve it, all of which are required to be idempotent by HTTP. Further, imagine the `id` field is generated by the server and returned in the response of the PUT request.

Now, I have two questions.

1. Given this sequence:

PUT /users/pparker `{"username": "pparker"}` returning `{"id": 3}`

DELETE /users/pparker (perhaps by a different client unaware of the first one)

PUT /users/pparker `{"username": "pparker"}` returning `{"id": 4}`

Is the PUT truly idempotent? (Not because of the different response - that is fine - but because the resource is now different.)

2. Given this sequence:

PUT /users/psimon `{"username": "psimon"}` returning `{"id": 5}`

PATCH /users/psimon `{"username": "psimon", "email": "psimon@example.com"}` (again, perhaps done by a second, unaware client)

PUT /users/psimon `{"username": "psimon"}` returning `{"id": 5}`

Should the second PUT delete the email (and be truly idempotent from the first client's perspective), or preserve it (and not break the second client's expectation)?

For the definition of idempotence in HTTP, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples are broken because `PUT /users` should *overwrite* your users collection. If you use a `PUT` request to create a user, I would expect a URI pattern like `PUT /users/123` where the client decides what the URI will be for the newly created user.

Returning something from a PUT request is (by default) not meaningful.

The purpose of a `PUT` request is to create or overwrite the resource at the target URI.

Comment: Right, my mistake, the URLs should have been /users/username in the examples.

Comment: I've corrected the error in the question and I'm still hoping for an answer that actually answers the question, which is about how idempotence is supposed to work.

Comment: @vashekcz `PUT` should not really return anything. `PUT` replaces the body of the resource you are creating. If you do a `GET` after it should roughly return what you initially sent with `PUT`. Why do you need an `id` here anyway? The url is your id.

Comment: @vashekcz if you want to return an `id` and change the body to include it, you should use something like `POST` which is not idempotent. But I recommend you avoid that.

Comment: That is really just your opinion on the API design though, which I respect but it is not the point of my questions. Perhaps focusing on the second question would be better. The point is, does idempotence mean I have to overwrite any changes that were done between retries of the same request? (In the first case, re-create the resource even though it was explicitly deleted in the meantime?)

Comment: The more I think about it, I think I have an answer to my own question, which is: this should never happen in practice, or at least should not be a relevant problem. I wonder if I should elaborate in a full answer.

Comment: @vashekcz it matters because you're at the outset using http methods incorrectly. The idempotent nature of PUT stems from using it as designed, which you are not.

Comment: Either I don't really understand what your objection is, or you're not actually reading what I wrote, or I simply disagree. If it's just about returning the `id` from the `PUT`, that's not important for the question - at least, certainly not for the second of the two, so feel free to ignore the return value. (But also, what's the core of what you believe is incorrect? Returning anything at all from PUT in general? Or generating any attribute on the server? Or having an extra identifier? Something else?)
It's not great API design, sure, but "incorrect"? To be clear, this "API" is hypothetical.

Comment: @vashekcz for clarify sake, I would suggest you take out response bodies from your question because it does confuse things. The main point is that if I run the same `PUT` twice, the server-state should be same as if I only did it once. If you want to return some arbitrary non-standard data that's fine but it should not be relevant to this question.

Comment: But idempotence is about server-state, not response bodies. You _may_ get different responses (for example as second DELETE is idempotent but may return a 404), but the server state is still identical.